# Ember.js - where to place server communication logic

Tags: ember.js, architecture

I'm having a problem figuring out what is the idiomatic Ember.js way of representing the following task: the application should display a list of master entries (let's call them **classes**) each one having one or more child entries (let's call them **students**), the latter having in turn **teacher-marks**, as sub-child entries.

I want the page to display the list of classes along with the list of students for each one as the standard view, while the **teacher-marks** should be initially hidden, but made visible on demand, when they should be editable in place (new and remove operations).

The way I've implemented this display-wise is this:

Each **class** is displayed as an Ember view, as I need a lot of interaction with the controller. The **teacher-marks** are implemented as Ember components, as well as the **students**. Neither the view, nor the components perform any communication with the server, they basically just send actions to the controller / route.

Displaying and hiding the **teacher-marks** are done via properties in the components.

I only have one route for all this (and as far as Ember.js tutorials and examples go, I feel I may be doing it wrong) and one controller. The route is named 'classes' and has an ArrayController displaying the array of **classes**. I have item controllers for each **class**.

The route object is the one that fetches data from the server. The manipulated child elements (e.g. new/removed **teacher-marks**) are pushed to the server via dedicated model functions (using Ajax calls) called from the main route events. I am not using Ember data.

As far as I read, I should be having nested resources for this implementation, but am otherwise at a loss as to how to implement it that way and keep displaying the **classes** and **students** at all times.

I would greatly appreciate all amendments and suggestions to the way I currently implemented this. It would also help me a great deal if you could add why will something work better one way or the other.

I haven't included any code as I feel it would be better expressed this way as a problem. My code is obviously more complicated than above, and not involving the class - students case. If needed, I can sketch-up a model.